# Jquery: events between two windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have openned a new window from my current page (click on a button).

```
<pre>
$(document).on("click","buttonInParentPage", function () {
    window.open("url, "popupWindow", "width=600,height=300,scrollbars=yes");
    return false;
});
</pre>
```

And I want, a clicked button from the new openned window, to execute a function in the current page (the parent page).

```
<pre>
$(document).on("click","buttonInNewWindow", function () {
    doSomeThingInParentPage();
});
</pre>
```

Any idea will be welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very very very much. This is exactly what I wanted to have. :)